Route Agents Dynamically using Omniflow
We recently transitioned from a queue-based routing system to a direct-to-agent routing system for our Enhanced SMS channel in our organization. Previously, any agent could accept work requests, but with this change, we aimed to dynamically assign work to agents based on the Contact Owner.
To implement this, we created an Omni-Channel Flow that queries the Messaging User's Contact and routes the work directly to the Contact Owner by passing their Agent ID in the Route Work action. The Service Channel is configured to support Messaging Sessions (liveMessage).
However, we’re experiencing issues with routing. While messages appear in the Messaging Sessions, the work isn’t assigned as expected. When debugging the Omni-Flow, it indicates that the Service Channel is invalid, although the configured Service Channel is indeed valid.
We’ve attempted several configurations, including:
Enabling Direct-to-Agent Routing in Omni-Channel settings. Setting the routing type to Omni-Flow and selecting the configured flow. Specifying a fallback queue for cases where routing doesn’t complete
.
Despite these adjustments, the routing still doesn’t function as intended.
Could anyone suggest any additional steps or configurations required to make Direct-to-Agent routing work effectively in this setup?
